# Tornado test coverage and pylint reports for jenkins

Tags: python, django, jenkins, tornado

For [`django`](https://www.djangoproject.com/) there are good module called [`django-jenkins`](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins).

Are there any modules for integrating [`tornado`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) in [`jenkins`](http://jenkins-ci.org/) available?